# Can I work with iPad iPhoto Journals from my desktop Mac?

Tags: ipad, aperture

iPad iPhoto journals are great... If my photos live primarily on my iPad. In my case though, they are on my iPad when I am traveling but end up on my Mac at home for long term storage. So if I make a pretty Journal on my iPad I would like to continue working on it in Aperture (or iPhoto) on my desktop. Sooner or later I want to remove the photos from my iPad because I need the storage.

Is there anyway to update and change my iPad/iPhoto Journals directly from my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent the better part of 6 hours researching this exact question, it appears that the answer is NO. I miss the mobileMe gallery more and more.